# Is there a way to find and remove multiple MongoDB documents in one query?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to optimize a time-based event queue that is managed in MongoDB. I'm regularly querying for due events (by checking their `due_time` value), executing due events and then removing executed events.

A shortened version of my Python code:

```py
def run(self):
    """
    Background process keeps pulling events from MongoDB and removes retrieved documents
    """
    while True:
        # Find all events that are due
        query = {'due_time': {'$lt': datetime.datetime.now()}}

        for event in self.mongo.db.events.find(query):
            # Do something
            pass
        
        self.mongo.db.events.remove(query)
        time.sleep(6)
```

I want to optimize my MongoDB calls. Is there a way I can reduce the two separate calls with the same query (`find(query)` and `remove(query)`) to one call, something like:

```py
due_events = self.mongo.db.events.find_and_then_remove(query)
```

Comment: What is "# Do something"? What is it you want to _do_ with _find_?

Comment: @prasad_
I added the part with "Do Something" to illustrate the context of my search. This is where application logic happens with the data I retrieved from MongoDB.

What I want to do is written at my final paragraph: I want to combine the effect of `find(query)` and `remove(query` in one MongoDB interaction if possible instead of calling `find` and `remove` separately.

Comment: You can try using [findOneAndDelete](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) - this returns the document deleted - on which you can perform the "Do Something". And, this happens in a loop until all matching documents are deleted - in a while loop. Which means, you delete the document first, and then Do Something (?) for each document.

Comment: @prasad_ Would repeated execution of [`findOneAndDelete`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndDelete/) be more efficient than 2 calls (one `find` and then one `remove`)?
In one iteration, there might be 30-40 documents that are retrieved by `find`. In such a case, would this be more efficient?

Comment: Each call to a CRUD operation is a trip to the database server (for one or multiple  document(s)). So, it is, in general, not efficient. The whole thing is, in your case, depends upon factors like how many documents are returned for a query (find and remove), what kind of job are you running? There are factors like that that influence the program design - efficiency, maintainability, performance (may be), etc, can be factors. In my opinion, you may want to try and see what works best in your case.

Comment: How many documents are returned per query: In production, I would estimate there will be 30-40 documents retrieved on an average `find`

The job that's running: Dispatched events will mostly perform `update_one` calls on the same database in a different collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to break if

- The system clock on the system which is processing the events is moved forward or backward
- Clocks on systems that insert entries into the queue are moved forward or backward

In either case you can remove entries that weren't processed.

What you should do is remove the documents that you have actually processed, identified by their _ids.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Systems that insert entries communicate only with a time-delta from the present moment, which should make the queue robust against changes in the system time of entry systems.
The processing system is planned to run only on one host machine with one system time (both the dispatch code and the MongoDB).
Thanks for the recommendation using the `_id` instead to remove documents!

Comment: That doesn't solve the first issue of the clock on the processing system being moved.

Comment: Would there be a solution to this that does not depend on the system clock?
I need to dispatch events based on **duration** that passed since (e.g. _dispatch event in 1024 seconds_ ).